# Multiple git repos within a git repo with same remote

Tags: git

I have some like following

```
parent/
  .git/
  README
  child1/
    .git/
    README
  child2/
    .git/
    README
  child3/
    .git/
```

I have access to only one remote. How can I manage such a structure where each child git repo can have its separate history? Thanks

Comment: Each directory with a proper `.git` folder is its own repository and doesn't share e.g. remotes with anything else in the tree. If they are intimidatingly related you could try using git submodules, if not a simple script to update them all would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

[Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) will accomplish what you you're looking for.  It allows one master repository to have multiple nested repositories and manage the sub repos with head references in the main repo.

One thing to note is that each sub repo has to have it's own repository through git.

Comment: I don't have own repo for each submodule. Thats what makes this difficult for me to handle in a single git repo !

Comment: Well that throws a wrench in the engine then.  I'm not sure there is a way to do it without the additional repos.  If the project wasn't sensitive I'd say public repos would work but that is rarely the case.  With what you're working with I'm thinking a branch system would be the only choice.  If you make all your updates in one folder on one branch and the other updates on another branch you could then keep track of the 'repo' branches and have a prod branch to merge all the branches into for production.  That's the only possible way I see with one single repository.